# Redux-persist Library: Pass persisted data to a react component

Tags: reactjs, redux-persist

I have integrated redux-persist to my app but I am struggling to pass the persisted data into react component. I want to have condition to check if the expire time (I am using redux-persist-transform-expire-in for expire time) has been expired before I make a call to api each time I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

use the `connect` function, provided by react-redux in order to connect the state to the components because redux-persist will pass every stored data to the redux reducers.

Comment: I have done that, the problem is, each time when I refresh the page it fetches the data from the server instead of getting it from the persisted data. I would to have a condition that checks if the persisted data has been expired or not then make a decision based on that.

Comment: So, check if the store had data, then prevent to fetching the API,